# Update list from external list on a timer

Tags: 2010, list, external-content-type

I have an external list which is generated from an external content type pointing towards my WCF service. I want to expose this list to my users but I don't want to spam the WCF service every time a page is refreshed by a user. Essentially I want to be hitting the service every 15 minutes, caching the results in the external list and only updating the cache when the time limit expires.

I thought about a couple of possible solutions but each one hit a dead end, mainly because I'm not experienced with sharepoint possibilities at the moment:

- A timed job which runs a workflow to copy the external list to another list every 15 minutes. Expose the other list to the users.
- Implement server side caching on the external list (I didn't find anything which indicated this was possible)

Anyone care to chip in with a plausible solution that I can investigate?

Answer (score -1):

Or you can even write a powershell script to 
[Copy List Items](http://adicodes.com/copy-or-replace-list-items-in-powershell/)
and run this through [Windows task scheduler](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx).

Comment: Can you please extend this answer to make it more helpful, e.g. how to write a PowerShell script and make it run through the scheduler?